# SOLR: Document is missing mandatory uniqueKey field: id

Tags: oracle11g, solr6

I have just started with the solr-6.5.1, trying to import data from Oracle DB.
My data does not have any Unique ID, searched through various forums and found out that using class="solr.UUIDUpdateProcessorFactory" this can be resolved. but stil getting the same error. below is the snippet of my managed-schema and solrconfig.xml.

solrconfig.xml

```
<requestHandler name="/update" class="solr.UpdateRequestHandler">
        <lst name="defaults">
            <str name="update.chain">uuid</str>
        </lst>
    </requestHandler>

    <updateRequestProcessorChain name="uuid">
        <processor class="solr.UUIDUpdateProcessorFactory">
            <str name="fieldName">id</str>
        </processor>
        <processor class="solr.RunUpdateProcessorFactory" />
    </updateRequestProcessorChain>
```

managed-schema

```
<field name="id" type="uuid" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" />
    <field name="SERVICEACCOUNTNUMBER" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" multiValued="false" /> 
    <field name="USERNAME" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" multiValued="false" />
    <field name="NAME" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true"  multiValued="false" />
    <field name="TRANSACTION_DATE" type="date" indexed="true" stored="true"  />
    <field name="PROCESSSTATUS" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" />
    <field name="RECHARGE_MODE" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true"  />
    <field name="PROCESSRECHARGEREQUESTNO" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true"  />
    <field name="PACKAGE_ID" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true"  />
    <field name="PACKAGENAME" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true"  />
    <field name="AMOUNT" type="int" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true" />
    <field name="CREDITDOCUMENTNUMBER" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true" />
    <field name="DEBITDOCUMENTNUMBER" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true"   />
    <field name="SERVICE_TYPE" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true" />
```

Please help

Answer (score 0):

answer credits to post [solr uuid with error document is missing mandatory uniquekey field id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41143842/solr-uuid-with-error-document-is-missing-mandatory-uniquekey-field-id)

updated the solrconfig.xml to

```
<requestHandler name="/dataimport" class="solr.DataImportHandler">
    <lst name="defaults">
      <str name="config">data-config.xml</str>
      <str name="update.chain">uuid</str>
    </lst>
 </requestHandler>

<updateRequestProcessorChain name="uuid">
      <processor class="solr.UUIDUpdateProcessorFactory">
          <str name="fieldName">id</str>
      </processor>
      <processor class="solr.RunUpdateProcessorFactory"/>
</updateRequestProcessorChain>
```